# Spatial autocorrelation coefficients interpretations

Tags: r, spatial-statistics, autocorrelation

I have this result for SDM estimates in R with R2 of 54%. Is the lambda (= -2.04) which is the spatial autocorrelation coefficient a plausible value? I have read in a book that [Elhorst, 2014, P.14], the spatial autocorrelation coefficient should be bounded between -1 and 1.

```
    > summary(ERVM)
Spatial panel fixed effects lag model


Call:
spml(formula = fmerv, data = spa.sakk, index = c("id", "months"), 
    listw = ERV, model = "within", effect = "time", lag = TRUE, 
    spatial.error = "none")

Residuals:
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-0.785173 -0.018300 -0.000716  0.016336  1.112927 

Spatial autoregressive coefficient:
       Estimate Std. Error t-value            Pr(>|t|)    
lambda   -2.403      0.111   -21.6 <0.0000000000000002 ***

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t-value             Pr(>|t|)    
spa.sakk$credk   0.00298    0.04250    0.07              0.94404    
spa.sakk$chexk   0.04923    0.03896    1.26              0.20633    
spa.sakk$uninfk  0.23803    0.26140    0.91              0.36250    
spa.sakk$gdpk    0.17135    0.33038    0.52              0.60401    
spa.sakk$chintk -4.53205    1.10230   -4.11             0.000039 ***
spa.sakk$lagret -0.26580    0.01386  -19.18 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
slervcredT       0.04790    0.14141    0.34              0.73480    
slervchecxT     -0.32075    0.12271   -2.61              0.00895 ** 
slervuninfT      7.46349    4.35165    1.72              0.08633 .  
slervgdpT        1.11652    1.01416    1.10              0.27093    
slervchintT     -6.41103    1.81507   -3.53              0.00041 ***
sllagret        -0.04978    0.05205   -0.96              0.33882    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```